# NSWindowController windowShouldClose Not Firing When Launched From Popup Menu

Tags: swift

I have a Preferences window controller that has a function that disables certain menu items when launched, the re-enables them when the window is closed.
The Preferences window is launched from the main application NSMenu and it works fine there but I just added a new popup menu that also launches the Preferences window. The menus get disabled on launch but never re-enabled on close. After some basic testing, the windowShouldClose and windowWillClose aren't firing when launched from the popup menu for some reason but work fine when called from the main NSMenu. I don't have a close button on the Window so the way the window is closed is by the red X on the titlebar

I am launching the window from the Popup menu like this;

```
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let preferencesWindow = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "preferencesWindow") as! NSWindowController
        preferencesWindow.window?.level = .floating
        preferencesWindow.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

The Preferences window is launched via Segue from the NSMainMenu and it works as expected there.
In my Preferences Controller, all I have is this;

```
class PreferencesWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        setSizeWindow()
        disableTVMenuItems()
    }

    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        print("Preferences window is closing")
        enableTVMenuItems()
        return true
    }
    
    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("Preferences window will close")
        enableTVMenuItems()
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I can't get this to work no matter what I tried. As a workaround and possibly a permanent solution is that I just simulate the keypresses for settings (Cmd+,) and that is working as expected. It is good enough but I would like to know why I can't get it work launching the Windows controller programatically instead of via NSMenu Segue